# How to show data of selected row in accodionPanel?

Tags: java, jsf, ejb, primefaces

I followed this example of datatable selection, and everything works fine:
[DataTable - Row Selection](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableRowSelectionSingle.jsf)

I tried to change this example and instead of dialog and panel grid, that shows up with data of selected row, I want accordionPanel with one tab and panel grid in that tab. At the beginning accordionPanel activeIndex="-1".

Here is my code:

```
<h:form id="formEditUser">
     <p:panel header="User Editing">
         <p:dataTable value="#{ikBean.userList}" var="user" id="usersTable" paginator="true" rows="5" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                             selection="#{ikBean.selectedUser}" selectionMode="single">
              <f:facet name="header">
                        Users
              </f:facet>

              <p:column filterBy="#{user.name}" headerText="Name" filterMatchMode="contains">
                  <h:outputText value="#{user.name}"/>
              </p:column>

              <p:column filterBy="#{user.surname}" headerText="Surname" filterMatchMode="contains">
                  <h:outputText value="#{user.surname}"/>
              </p:column>

              <p:column filterBy="#{user.jmbg}" headerText="JMBG" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                  <h:outputText value="#{user.jmbg}"/>
              </p:column>

              <p:column filterBy="#{user.userName}" headerText="User Name" filterMatchMode="startsWith" style="width: 120px;">
                  <h:outputText value="#{user.userName}"/>
              </p:column>

              <f:facet name="footer">
                   <p:commandButton value="Edit" image="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh"
                                         update=":formEditUser:display" oncomplete="accordionEdit.select(0)"/>

                   <p:commandButton value="Clear" image="ui-icon ui-icon-close" process=":@this" update="usersTable"/>
              </f:facet>

          </p:dataTable>

          <p:accordionPanel activeIndex="-1" widgetVar="accordionEdit">
                    <p:tab title="User Editing">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10" id="display">
                            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name: "/>
                            <p:inputText id="name" required="true" label="name" size="25" value="#{ikBean.selectedUser.name}"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:tab>
          </p:accordionPanel>
      </p:panel>
 </h:form>
```

My result is: collapsed tab (that is what i wanted, but) without any data in it. Of course, I forgot to mention that in panel grid I have some input text fields...everything like the primefaces example. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

add prependId to your  and try both values - True or False . It been a while I forgot is it false or true and let me know is it working or not.